# Show ImageView as long as the ImageView is pressed

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. I'm trying to implement a method that shows an `overlay(container_dia)` over my `ImageView(container_post)` which contains information of the posted image (for example: Date, filename, etc.).

The `overlay(container_dia)` should just be shown as long as the user presses the ImageView. For that I wrote this here:

```
  fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mView.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
            fadeIn.setDuration(100);
            fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mView.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fadeOut.setDuration(100);

            container_post = (RelativeLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.container_post);
            container_post.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            container_diagramm = (RelativeLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.container_diagramm);
            container_diagramm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ImageView postImageLouminadeStream = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.postImageLouminadeContent);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(postImageLouminadeStream);
            postImageLouminadeStream.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            container_post.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                            container_post.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                            container_diagramm.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                            container_diagramm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            container_post.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                            container_post.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                            container_diagramm.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                            container_diagramm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            container_post.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                            container_post.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                            container_diagramm.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                            container_diagramm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

I've read that this should be the right method for my intention but it just works like an normal `onClickListener`, because when my finger leaves the screen the `overlay` stays. And when I press the `Image` again it shows the `Image` for a split second and then the overlay appears again. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you're happy enough to use a library to get the same affect, you could try
https://github.com/RiccardoMoro/LongPressPopup